# My diode bridge rectifier circuit in LTspice does not work properly

Tags: ltspice, simulation, bridge-rectifier

I am trying to make a model of a diode bridge rectifier in LTspice (it has to be connected to a transformer as it's part of a larger project).

I have tested the transformer and the rectifier independently and they seem to work. However, when I put them together, they don't work as expected (images attached).

The problem I'm facing seems to be the placement of the ground: when I place it near the transformer, so its AC ground, I am getting some waveforms, though not very clean. A little digging around suggested that I should have placed the ground at the DC side, but this does not give me any output at all. Any help would be appreciated.

When Ground is placed near the transformer:
[image: When Ground is placed near the transformer]

The green waveform in the first image is the output of the transformer; the blue and red waveforms are at the top and bottom of the resistor respectively.

When Ground is placed near the resistor:
[image: When Ground is placed near the resistor]

Scale is only upto 33 microseconds, there is a statement at the bottom which says that the analysis is 0% done.

Comment: You're using the ST model for the rectifiers? Maybe that's the issue. Also, please label  your nodes with human-readable names. Things like n007 not only cannot be easily read, they can change if you modify the circuit.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm not using the ST models actually. That's the model I'm supposed to use for the project, which wasn't working, so I wanted to test it out with the default diode provide by LTSPICE. Apologies for not naming the nodes, I'm just getting started with the software.

Comment: The first image looks correct to me - this really is how your waveforms look when you use a diode bridge - both the + and - side are live and you shouldn't touch either one (if using dangerous voltages). In the second one I guess the simulator is having some trouble running the simulation even though the circuit is okay. Simulators using ideal diode models (are you?) it can run into similar issues because  the transformer secondary has no voltage reference. What if you add some high resistance such as 10M ohms between one side of the transformer and ground - then does the simulation run?

Comment: @user253751 it does run, thank you! Added a 10M ohm resistor on secondary side.

Comment: @winny There is no AC-secondary-side grounding in the second example though?

Comment: @winny Those grounds are required or SPICE doesn't like it. The transformer provides isolation so it won't affect the simulation.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Oh! Sorry, I see where my train of though went wrong here. Floating secondary casuing LTspice to get confused? Add 1 megaogm to ground on the secondary side?

Comment: @winny Yes,  1 MEG would work (new users should beware that 1M = 0.001Ω), but in this case we might as well ground it directly.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany backwards. 1m (lower case m) = 0.001

Comment: @user253751 LTSpice does not follow that convention, so 1M = 1m = 0.001 ohm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the diode models with real diodes of adequate rating for the situation (right click on the diode, pick new diode).

Or put a resistor (maybe 20kΩ) across the input to the bridge rectifier.

You've got something there that's too ideal and likely causing some issue with the solver. It's nothing directly to do with the placement of the ground.

Here it is working with a real diode model (with the default diode model it has issues)

[image]